# For each different row on a column, keep only the top N row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to aggregate the rows on this table. I want to eliminate duplicated bundle id's and keep only the most installed app name for each bundle ID. As you can see on the image, there are several different bundle id's right now

[image]

I tried to group by it, however if I group by bundle ID only it works but the app name doesn't appear. I want to remove duplicates for bundle ID'S and keep the app name with most installations (count) so I would like something like this comparing to the image:

Bundle ID     app name    count
.apps.Photos   photos      3,530

Comment: For the future note that this is the worst possible way to post the sample data.  It should be text we can copy to try to solve your problem, not things for us to retype from an image. What's worse, the image is terrible, probably a photo of a screen using a phone rather then a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI/PowerQuery using M

It is unclear if you want the sum of the App_Bundle counts, or the count of just the largest App_Name in each Bundle, but here is both

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"App_Bundle_ID"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Count", Order.Descending}}),1), type table [App_Bundle_ID=text, App_Name=text, Count=number]}, {"MasterCount", each List.Sum([Count]), type number}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"App_Name", "Count"}, {"App_Name", "Count"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

if you dont want the count column then use

```
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"App_Name"}, {"App_Name"})
```

Comment: Oh sorry, would be the sum of all the same bundle ID's. The idea on the green table is almost what I want, but I want the sum and not only the number of the most installed app name